# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.icenibees.apiarymanager.AMClasses$Inspection

Tags: java, android, sqlite, class, casting

I'm trying to query a row from an SQLite DB and display fields on the screen. I have a method in my DateSource where I use a cursor to put the row into my Inspection class and return it. Then I'm trying to put that returned class into an Inspection object in my activity so I can use my getters to retrieve the fields and display them. It's the second line that throws the error. I can paste more info if required. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong. I've tried different combinations of casting, but I'm just shooting in the dark. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
AMClasses.Inspection currentInspection = new AMClasses.Inspection();
currentInspection = (AMClasses.Inspection) mDataSource.getCurrentInspectionRecord();
hiveQueenStatus = currentInspection.getQueenstatus();
```

UPDATE:

Seem to fixed it:-

I'm reading the list into variables and then into my class.

```
List<Inspection> currentInspectionFromDB = mDataSource.getCurrentInspectionRecord();

        for(int i = 0; i < currentInspectionFromDB.size(); i++)
        {
            Inspection temp = currentInspectionFromDB.get(i);
            inspectionID = temp.getInspectionid();
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Current Inspection ID: " + inspectionID);
            inspectionHiveID = temp.getInspectionhiveid();
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Current Inspection Hive ID: " + inspectionHiveID);
            inspectionNumSupers = temp.getNumsupers();
            inspectionQx = temp.getQx();
```

Comment: what exception you are getting ?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.icenibees.apiarymanager/com.icenibees.apiarymanager.inspections.InspectionStart}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.icenibees.apiarymanager.AMClasses$Inspection